# VBA - Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range when executing .SaveAs

Tags: excel, vba

I have read thru numerous questions/replies and have yet to find the solution to my issue.  I am copying data from one workbook/worksheet to a new workbook, single worksheet.  Everything in my code is working as expected/needed until the line where I am trying to save the new output excel file ("wbSaveAs Filename:=").

See/review my code:

```
    Sub SAVEAS_EXCEL()

    'Variables
    Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled

    Dim TheList As Object       'Range of numbers on List
    Dim N As Variant            'Temp integer for stepping through ForEach number on List
    Dim i As Integer            'Counter
    Dim m As String             'Month for filename
    Dim y As Integer            'Year for filename
    Dim d As Date               'Date value
    Dim s As String             'Counter as string plus msgbox info
    Dim sPath As String         'Path to store new file
    Dim OutputFile As String    'Name of report file exported to Excel
    Dim wsCopy As Worksheet     'Sheet that is copied
    Dim wsPaste As Worksheet    'Used to paste values
    Dim wb As Workbook          'New workbook


    d = Date
    m = MonthName(Month(d))
    y = Year(d)
    sPath = "C:\Users\me\"

    'Make the List sheet active
    Sheets("List").Activate

    'Select a range of cells (with data) on the List sheet
    Set TheList = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A2")
    'Switch back to the main control worksheet
    Sheets("Setup Instructions").Activate

    'Study counter
    i = 1

    'Cycle through each item in the list
    For Each N In TheList
    'If the collected field is not empty
    If N <> "" Then
        Sheets("Setup Instructions").Activate
        'Set target field to study number value
        ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value = N
        'If the font color is red, Report w Fees
        If N.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
            Sheets("Report w Fees").Activate
            ActiveSheet.Calculate
            Set wsCopy = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report w Fees")
            Set wb = Workbooks.Add
            Set wsPaste = wb.Sheets(1)
        Else
            'If the font color is NOT red, Report NO Fees
            Sheets("Report NO Fees").Activate
            ActiveSheet.Calculate
            Set wsCopy = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report NO Fees")
            Set wb = Workbooks.Add
            Set wsPaste = wb.Sheets(1)
        End If
        'Copy everything from copy sheet
        wsCopy.Cells.Copy
        wsPaste.Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        wsPaste.Columns("K:M").EntireColumn.Delete
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False
        wsPaste.Rows("2:2").Select
        ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
        OutputFile = N & " " & m & " " & y & " Report.xlsx"
    
        'Save new workbook
        wsPaste.Name = N & " Report"
        Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Name
        Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.Name
        wb.SaveAs Filename:=sPath & OutputFile, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook

        'Increase the counter
        i = i + 1
        End If
    Next

    'Convert the counter to a string and join with user message
    s = Str(i - 1) & " Reports were exported to Excel format"
    MsgBox [s], 0, "Excel Export Utility"

    End Sub
```

The excel file gets created with the correct filename in the correct directory...then, instead of the counter increasing and the next item in the list getting processed, the Run-time error '9' message pops up.

Any thoughts/ideas?  Thank you so much in advance!

Don

Comment: I would stat by avoiding `Activate` and by qualifying the workbook for every instance of `Sheets("...")` and `Worksheets("...")`.

Comment: It wouldn't be error 9 so execution must be halted before that line but why the square brackets around `[s]`? If you mean to refer to local variable `s`, then that should be `MsgBox s`. The square brackets are forwarding the evaluation of the expression to Excel, so unless there's a range named `s`, the result of `[s]` would be a `#NAME?` error... which would throw a *type mismatch* as the `Variant/Error` value fails to be passed as a `String` argument for the `MsgBox` function.

Comment: Also `N As Variant` is a `Variant/Range` at run-time, not an integer (that comment is misleading!); declaring `N As Range` would give you compiler assistance when accessing its members; any member call against `Variant` can only be late-bound. If the file gets created, then the `wb.SaveAs` instruction isn't where the error is being thrown. I suspect the loop is simply entering a second iteration and the `ActiveWorkbook` isn't the same workbook as it was the first time around. Try adding `ThisWorkbook.Activate` just before the `Next` line; if it "fixes" it, rework the implicit ActiveSheet refs.

Comment: Mathieu - many thanks!  The "ThisWorkbook.Activate" just before the Next resolved the problem.  You rock, my friend!